# What is the purpose of setting SQL TRUSTWORTHY ON

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

I am using the tSQLt testing framework and the pre-requisite is to set the database to TRUSTWORTHY, using the below code:

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX); SET @cmd='ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + ' SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;'; EXEC(@cmd);
```

What is the purpose of setting TRUSTWORTHY ON?

Comment: Not enough for an answer, but if you set `TRUSTWORTHY ON` it will allow you to execute functions/procedures that require server level permissions, even if the current user does not have those permissions (IIRC).

Comment: [All what you need](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: can you put in an answer so i can mark it as answer please

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of `tSQLt`? [According to these release notes](https://tsqlt.org/748/tsqlt-v1-0-5873-27393-release-notes/), `TRUSTWORTHY` is no longer required. It was previously needed because the assembly wasn't pre-signed.